# Test iOS9 SDK using Swift with older SDK version

Tags: ios, unit-testing, testing, macros, force-touch

I faced with a problem during writing test for the ForceTouch. My app is available for iOS8-9. 
I write `@available(iOS 9.0, *)` in my develop target and it works fine in iOS8 and its just ignored by compiler.
But I catch the exception: `Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIApplicationShortcutItem` on test target.
I know that macros don't work on Swift.

```
NSProcessInfo.processInfo().isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion
```

the compiler ignores too.
The question is how to test methods from iOS9 SDK if your app available for older version iOS too?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

This fixed it for me, make sure the deployment target is iOS8 also on your Test Target.

[image]